# I have a set of images rendered, but when trying to make it flex, the content is too large

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this code in where I try to map through an array of data to get the images rendered in my Shop component. I'm trying to make the images align in columns of 4, but when I try it, as there are 8 images, all of the images are displayed vertically, but I want it to divide it 4 and 4. Here is a image to explain it better:

[image]

As you can see below, there is a scrollbar for the 4 remaining images, but I want 4 images in a row and 4 in another one. How can that be done? I've tried some flex properties but it is not working...

```
import React from 'react'
import data from './data.js'

function Shop({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" src={img}></img>
              <div>
                <button>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

CSS:

```
.div___navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.img___home {
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.img___shop {
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.div___shop {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex-wrap: wrap;` in flex parent.

> **Wrap**: The flex items break into multiple lines. The cross-start is either
> equivalent to start or before depending flex-direction value and the
> cross-end is the opposite of the specified cross-start